# How extract interface from exist class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want extract interface from class so that not duplicate method declaration in class and interface.

```
typeof MyClass
```

not extract interface,
also I think what I can use simple MyClass intead insterface
but MyClass contain information about private methods and params

```
class MyClass {
  public get() {}
  private secret() {}
}

function run(e: MyClass) {  // need work with MyClassInterface
  e.get();
}

run(new MyClass());

run({
  get: () => {} // require secret method
});

run({
  get:() => {},
  secret: () => {}, // require what secret be private
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following type extracts public members from `MyClass`:

```js
type MyClassInterface = { [k in keyof MyClass]: MyClass[k] };
```

Reference: [Microsoft/TypeScript#471](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/471#issuecomment-381842426)